# CSS псевдоклассы

Tags: css3

Возник вот такой вопрос. Концепция в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, она должна остаться с теми стилями, что и при hover. При нажатии на следующую ссылку то же самое, но у предыдущей стиль возвращался к исходному. Через focus сделать не получается. Подскажите, кто может, пожалуйста. Фото прилагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.tabsLink {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.tabsLink a {
  user-select: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
  color: #2196f3;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #2196f3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.tabsLink a:hover {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.tabsLink li:focus~a {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabsLink">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#okk">ОКК</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ooa">OOA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#otp">ОТП</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - использовать псевдокласс `:target`

```css
.tabsLink {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.tabsLink a {
  user-select: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
  color: #2196f3;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #2196f3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.tabsLink a:hover {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.tabsLink a:target {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabsLink">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="okk" href="#okk">ОКК</a></li>
    <li><a id="ooa" href="#ooa">OOA</a></li>
    <li><a id="otp" href="#otp">ОТП</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Для перехода к выбранному фрагменту документа, в адресе пишется символ # и указывается имя идентификатора. К примеру, в адресе `http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo` происходит переход к элементу, атрибут `id` которого задан как `target-pseudo`. Такая запись адреса называется «целевой элемент». Псевдокласс `:target` применяется к целевому элементу, иными словами, к идентификатору, который указан в адресной строке браузера.

Источник: [Псевдокласс :target | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/css/target)

---

Реализация на JQ

**Вариант с "единичным выбором"**

```js
$('.tabsLink a').on('click', function(){
  // Ниже условие, которое НЕ даёт выполнять действие, если "нажатая" ссылка имеет класс "active"
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    // Найдём "активную" ссылку и удалим у неё класс active
    $(this) // обращаемся к текущему элементу
      .closest('.tabsLink') // вызвращаемся подереву назад до .tabsLink
      .find('a.active') // Ищем ссылку с классом "active"
      .removeClass('active'); // Удаляем класс "active"
      
    // Вешаем нажатой ссылке класс "active" 
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
  return false; // отключаем переход по ссылке
});
```

```css
.tabsLink {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.tabsLink a {
  user-select: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
  color: #2196f3;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #2196f3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.tabsLink a:hover, /* т.к. у "активной ссылки" стили такие же как и при наведение, то совместим свойства для действия "hover" и класса "active" */
.tabsLink a.active {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  -->
<div class="tabsLink">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#okk">ОКК</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ooa">OOA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#otp">ОТП</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Вариант с "мульти-выбором"**

```js
$('.tabsLink a').on('click', function(){
  // > Тут гораздо проще, чем в предыдущем варианте.
  // .toggleClass позваляет удалять\добавлять класс на элемент, в зависимости от того, есть ли такой класс там или нету.
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  return false; // отключаем переход по ссылке
});
```

```css
.tabsLink {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.tabsLink a {
  user-select: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
  color: #2196f3;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #2196f3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.tabsLink a:hover, /* т.к. у "активной ссылки" стили такие же как и при наведение, то совместим свойства для действия "hover" и класса "active" */
.tabsLink a.active {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  -->
<div class="tabsLink">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#okk">ОКК</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ooa">OOA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#otp">ОТП</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Будет ли .tabsLink a:target зависеть от родительского элемента? К примеру div class="tabsLink" лежит в родителе со стилями:
.tabs_add{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  justify-content: center;
}

Вопрос к тому, что у меня, к сожалению target не работает(

Comment: Скорее всего что-то не так писали, ибо он `:target` не зависит от стилей родителя, ну только в том случае, если будет так `.tabs_add .tabsLink a:target {}`

Comment: Да, действительно, не так прописал. Дело в том, что ссылки на id уже прикреплены. Это работает посредством "вкладок". Таким образом, id="okk" и тд уже прикреплены к ссылкам, но в другом месте(
Если сделать так как вы, то все работает, но вкладки уже не открывает.
Кроме таргета есть еще вариант, либо можно ли как-то доработать?

Comment: Я бы не стал заморачиваться над таргетами и написал бы на JS\JQ.

Comment: К сожалению, знания пока не позволяют. Можете помочь? Если вас не затруднит, конечно

Comment: Обновил вопрос под реализацию на Jquery